# My pool shows no evidence of block that my computer discovered

Tags: mining-pools

It appears that my computer discovered a block i.e. bfgminer printed an *Accepted* line, but in my *BTC Guild* account there is no evidence of this and in fact, their records of when my computer last took part in the pool are wrong. 
Given the hex number of my block, is there any way for me to track down the block to find out what happened to it?

UPDATE: Turns out the Accepted share was a test share, used to detect botnet machines.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you mining at some absurdly low speed? If so, you're probably so close to zero as is considered effectively equal to it.

Comment: I thought you had solved a block. But if this is just a normal "accepted" message that just means you did a tiny bit of work that you will be paid for. Normally you see those every few seconds unless you have a very very low hashrate (CPU mining etc).

Answer (score 3):

Pooled mining lowers the difficulty that it reports to miners and the results are submitted as proof of work to the pool, so they can pay you.  Only a small portion of submitted shares are valid solutions to an actual block.